# Phone dialer app that allows you to disable the proximity sensor?

Tags: android, phone

I'm on OxygenOS 11 based on Android 11 with a OnePlus 8 phone. I would like to disable the proximity sensor during calls.

Old versions of the Google Phone Dialer app (e.g. v23) exposed this option in the settings, but more recent versions of the app don't have it. I've also tried a bunch of Phone Dialer apps from the Play Store and couldn't find any that expose this option. I also can't install v23 of the Google Phone Dialer because it's missing a shared library. I've also searched through this forum and all the old posts regarding disabling the proximity sensor don't work on this version of Android.

Does anyone know of any Phone Dialer app that allows you to disable the proximity sensor during calls? Or any app that allows you to disable the proximity sensor specifically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I found. It's a recompiled Dialer apk that is old, version 19 https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-disable-proximity-sensor-in-nougat.3453008/page-6#post-80918151

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old but I will post the solution that has worked for me after a long and hard search.

Install an android app called "Right Dialer" from Google Play, link here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodwy.dialer . Then go to settings and toggle "Disable Proximity Sensor During Calls".

Answer (score 0):

I already tried and installed these two apps on my phone, they work well especially if you have a problem with your smartphone about Proximity sensor display during a call.

1. [Dialer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-disable-proximity-sensor-in-nougat.3453008/page-6#post-80918151)
2. [Right Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodwy.dialer)

Comment: Welcome, the idea is that you give them a review.  Are you able expand on their pros and cons